# Netbeans 7.3.1 Cannot Cancel Java Debug

Tags: debugging, netbeans, windows-xp

I am running Netbeans 7.3.1 on XP. If I cancel a debug session, the process often doesn't end. I seem to recall seeing a similar bug report on Version 6.XX and was marked fixed.

Anyone else has the same problem?

Comment: I suggest you updating your NetBeans IDE to fix those bugs,if any!But,it might be possible because of your system's huge process assessment!

Comment: Just checked for updates. It says my version is up to date.